# How can I reference a razor page's partial view from a MVC page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

How can I reference a razor page's partial view from a MVC page?

I have a controller that handles returning a lot of reporting related requests. For one particular report I want to reference a partial view in the same project but in a razor page's folder. I could easily copy it to the Report Controllers folder `Reports/Views/Shared` but for better organization I would like to keep it in my Razor page's shared views folder. I tried to reference the page exactly as a razor page would but it throws an error saying the view was not found even showing the location as I specified.

`@await Html.PartialAsync("/Areas/MyRzrFolder/Views/Shared/_mypartial", Model)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the extension ".cshtml" at the end of the view path. This fixed it for me.

`@await Html.PartialAsync("/Areas/MyRzrFolder/Views/Shared/_mypartial.cshtml", Model)`

Comment: WOW! .cshtml is indeed required when accessing a partial razor view from a MVC page but not from within a razor page. Interesting quirk Microsoft!